# powershell xml sort nodes and replacechild

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to do something pretty simple with powershell and xml but haven't a bit of trouble.
Basically I'm trying to take the following xml... and sort the machine elements by name. Then put them back into the XML so that I can save back to a file.

Sorting seems to be working if output the $new object however, during the replacechild it's complaining "Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "System.Object[]" for "ReplaceChild" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode" : "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode".

If I do a Get-Member on both $orig and $new they both say they are of type XMLElement which I believe inherits from XMLNode.

What am I missing guys? Driving me nuts. Thanks for your help!

```
<company>
    <stuff>
    </stuff>
    <machines>
        <machine>
            <name>ca</name>
            <b>123</b>
            <c>123</c>
        </machine>
        <machine>
            <name>ad</name>
            <b>234</b>
            <c>234</c>
        </machine>
        <machine>
            <name>be</name>
            <b>345</b>
            <c>345</c>
        </machine>
    </machines>
    <otherstuff>
    </otherstuff>
</company>

[xml]$xml = (get-content Company.xml)
[XmlNode]$orig = $xml.Company.Machines
[XmlNode]$new = ($orig.Machine | sort Name )
$xml.Company.ReplaceChild($new, $orig)
```

Comment: I found a general XML-ordering script, useful for comparing two similar XML files. [Diff XML, via sorting XML elements and attributes](https://danielsmon.com/2017/03/10/diff-xml-via-sorting-xml-elements-and-attributes/)

Answer (score 5):

There are various problems here. One is that your `sort` returns a list of xml elements rather than a single xml element. Another problem is that it returns the original xml elements rather than copies, so any manipulation of the xml DOM that you do using them will also affect the result.

Here's a simple way to get what you want. Sort in *reverse* order, and then insert each node in turn in front of the others. Each time you insert a node from the result of the sort it will automatically remove it from the original set of node:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<company>
    <stuff>
    </stuff>
    <machines>
        <machine>
            <name>ca</name>
            <b>123</b>
            <c>123</c>
        </machine>
        <machine>
            <name>ad</name>
            <b>234</b>
            <c>234</c>
        </machine>
        <machine>
            <name>be</name>
            <b>345</b>
            <c>345</c>
        </machine>
    </machines>
    <otherstuff>
    </otherstuff>
</company>
"@
[System.Xml.XmlNode]$orig = $xml.Company.Machines
$orig.Machine | sort Name  -Descending |
  foreach { [void]$xml.company.machines.PrependChild($_) }
$xml.company.machines.machine
```

Edit: The pipeline can also be written with an ascending sort (as David Martin pointed out), and you can reduce typing by using the node in the variable:

```
$orig.Machine | sort Name | % { [void]$orig.AppendChild($_) }
```

Comment: looks really good - I would have to RemoveAll before adding them back in otherwise i'd have twice as many correct?

Comment: No, that was my point about them being the original nodes rather than copies: when you insert the node back into the tree it moves it from it's original location. (The code I posted is a complete sample, you should be able to copy/paste it and see the effect).

Comment: @DavidMartin, no you can also sort ascending and AppendChild instead. I'm a little bit wary about manipulating the child nodes that way round as iterating over a list to which you are appending feels like there's a risk of an infinite loop, but that isn't an issue here.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't work is that $xml.Company.Machines is a single XmlElement. To get the collection of machine elements, you need to use $xml.Company.Machines.Machine, so this is the one you want to sort.

However, the ReplaceChild method doesn't take a collection, so I'm guessing you'll have to remove all children and then append them back in the order you want them. Something like the following should work fine:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content .\Company.xml
$machines = $xml.company.machines
$orderedMachineCollection = $machines.machine | Sort Name
$machines.RemoveAll()
$orderedMachineCollection | foreach { $machines.AppendChild($_) } | Out-Null
```

Comment: yep, this is exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for confirming the reasons!

Comment: @RobertWesterlund I implemented your solution, running my script with PowerShell ISE I can see how the order of the nodes changes, but then I save the changes to the file and it does not change at all.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the already excellent answers by Duncan and robert.westerlund I'd like to provide an example of how to do the sorting of xml elements in case the nodes are not always in the same path:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<config>
    <namespace name='Some namespace'>
        <settings>
            <setting name='c setting' />
            <setting name='a setting' />
            <setting name='b setting' />
        </settings>
        <namespace name='Child namespace'>
            <settings>
                <setting name='z setting' />
                <setting name='y setting' />
                <setting name='x setting' />
            </settings>
        </namespace>
    </namespace>
</config>
"@

#[xml]$xml = Get-Content "PATH_TO_SOME_FILE.xml"

$xml.SelectNodes("//namespace/settings") | % { 
    $parentNode = $_; $_.Setting | Sort-Object -Property name | % { 
        $parentNode.AppendChild($_) | Out-Null
    } 
}

$xml.Save("PATH_TO_SOME_FILE.xml")
```

In this example, the `settings` node appears on different levels in the xml file and sorting is done with respect to this level.