# Sort XML nodes by multiple criteria

Tags: xml, powershell, sorting

I'm trying to sort the following XML by date as main criteria and then price as second criteria.

I thought it's sufficient to sort it based on price first and then sort it by date. I expected book `bk108` to end up first due to being the newest with highest price, but instead the first book is `bkXXX` even though its price is lower than `bk108`'s.

```xml
$xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>1000</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>1000</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>999</price>
      <publish_date>2001-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
    <book id="bkXXX">
      <author>new auth</author>
      <title>some title</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>998</price>
      <publish_date>2001-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>would go here</description>
   </book>
     <book id="bk113">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>999</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
'@
```

```ps
[System.Xml.XmlNode]$orig = $xml.catalog
$orig.book | sort { [double] $_.price}  |
  foreach { [void]$xml.catalog.PrependChild($_) }
$xml.catalog.book

[System.Xml.XmlNode]$orig = $xml.catalog
$orig.book | sort { [DateTime] $_.publish_date}  |
  foreach { [void]$xml.catalog.PrependChild($_) }
$xml.catalog.book

$xml.Save('c:\work\foo.xml')
```

This was my starting point [powershell xml sort nodes and replacechild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104514/powershell-xml-sort-nodes-and-replacechild)

Comment: Currently you're sorting by one parameter at a time. First you only look at the price and sort by that and afterwards you look at the date and only sort by date. Naturally you would end up with a list that is only sorted by date at the end. Furthermore your sorting is somewhat unusual as [`Sort-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) doesn't accept a code block.

Comment: `bk108` is the newest and the most expensive one, not `bk105`.

Comment: typo, sorry about that i will change it in description

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code after `[System.Xml.XmlNode]$orig = $xml.catalog` with this:

```
[xml]$sortedXml = @"
    <catalog>
        $(($orig.book | sort-object -Property {[double] $_.price},{[datetime]$_.publish_date} -descending).OuterXml)
    </catalog>
"@
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid writing <catalog> </catalog> tags? Xml structure of my file is a bit complicated. Thanks. But this could work only to switch places between publish date and price